# CUDA could not resolve local variables with names starting on _ZTV

Tags: c++, cuda

CUDA could not resolve local variables with names starting on _ZTV

I am debugging a CUDA application with Nsight.
Once (and I don't know how) it happened to appear 10 new local variables with stange names, some of them:

```
_ZTVNSt8ios_base7failureE
_ZTVSt12system_error
_ZTVSt5ctypelcE
_ZTVSt10ctype_base
```

And others. Sometimes they are just arrays of different length, containing zeros. Sometimes it says "Could not resolve name '...'" for every variable. And if it could not - the app doesn't work.
Now the funny thing. Its ability to resolve that names differs. For example:

```
__global__ void GPUInit(int z)
{
    //Can't resolve names
}
```

But if I add another function, like this

```
__global__ void GPUInit2(int z)
{
    //Ok
}
__global__ void GPUInit(int z)
{
    //Ok
}
```

everyone works.
It could happen that we successfully enter a `__global__` function, but can't resolve names in a regular `__device__` function

Help me, please to figure out what it is and how I can handle it.

Comment: First, clean everything. Now I wonder if your compiler is mismatched with the system libraries. This can happen because nvcc might not be set to the system's compiler.

Comment: Clean what? And how? All I know is that I do use nvcc. Otherwise, it would't work at all..

Comment: Just FYI: `c++filt _ZTVNSt8ios_base7failureE` gives `vtable for std::ios_base::failure` and `c++filt _ZTVSt12system_error` gives `vtable for std::system_error`...

Comment: nvcc wraps gcc, it might be wrapping a misconfigure configured version.